# What's the meaning of "falling" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He saved a little girl from ***falling*** into the water.

In this example sentence, what does the "***falling***" means?

> 1. The girl was about to fall into the water, but didn't yet.
> 2. The girl fell into the water, and then he rescued the drowning girl.
> 3. Something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save someone *from falling* indicates that they have not yet *fallen*.    The use of "from" is important, as it indicates preventing an action before it happens:

It would be the same with any similar action:

> He stopped her from **drinking** the old milk.
>
> She turned the wheel to keep from **running** off the road.
>
> He forbade them from **playing** in the rain.

And so on.

If instead you wanted to say that the girl already *fell*, then often the past or the past perfect are used:

> He saved a little girl who **fell/had fallen** into the water.

With a different grammar structure you can use "falling", but with some adverb like "after":

> **After falling in the water**, the girl was rescued by a passing stranger.